# Git says `Everything up-to-date` but Github is 61 commits behind master

Tags: git, github, rebase

I'm contributing to a big project on Github, I made 25 commits for this PR but I'm 61 commits behind and I need to rebase the project.

There is a no-merge policy, so I can't merge it, I need to rebase. Everytime I use `git pull` the output is `Everything up-to-date`. But not everything is up to date because I don't want to pull out of my fork, I want to get those 61 commits from the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the upstream repo as a remote, and pull from that instead. For example:

```
$ git remote add upstream git@github.com:user/repo.git
$ git pull upstream main
```